# Split and breakdown part of folder path in php

Tags: php, string

I have the following folder paths:

```
c:/data/2/some_string/ddd.jpg
c:/data/data/2/some_string/ddd.jpg
c:/data/some_string/ddd.jpg
```

I would like to get always the "some_string/ddd.jpg". 
How can I do that?

I can do it for specific path ,but I need something more dynamically

thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: you want file's name, extension and name of parent folder, right?

Comment: the "123132" is static and you are looking for the position? What is special about this 123132? Give us more information to understand how to locate it. Your URL can have also fields that are similar to this one? The number of characters in the field you are interested is static (6 characters). And most important. What have you tried?

Comment: @pr1nc3 updated my question

Comment: You need somehting dynamical, but what could change ? can `some_string` change ? can `ddd.jpg` change ? only `ddd` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple combination of [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$somefile = 'c:/data/data/2/123132/some_string/ddd.jpg';

echo basename(dirname($somefile)) . '/' . basename($somefile);
```

Output:

```
some_string/ddd.jpg
```

It works that way: 1) get full path to parent folder, 2) get filename of that folder (as folders are special kind of files).

It works also for non-existent files and folders as these functions simply process path string.

Comment: Is it not missing the filename?

Comment: @JuanFerrer, OP edited the question and added filename. I'll updated my answer.

Comment: I liked your answer the best, but it wasn't up to date. +1 now =]

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string with [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) into an array.
Then you could loop over it and compare it to the wanted path.

```
<?php

  $path = 'c:/data/2/123132/ddd.jpg';
  $chunks = explode('/', $path);

  /*
    array(5) {
      [0]=> string(2) "c:" 
      [1]=> string(4) "data" 
      [2]=> string(1) "2" 
      [3]=> string(6) "123132" 
      [4]=> string(7) "ddd.jpg"
    }
  */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var1='c:/data/2/some_string/ddd.jpg';
$var2='c:/data/data/2/some_string/ddd.jpg';
$var3='c:/data/some_string/ddd.jpg';



    $data=strrev($var1);
$newstr = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, '/', strpos($data, '/')+1));
$newstr=strrev($newstr);
    echo $newstr;
```

No matter how long the string is it will always return the part you want

```
some_string/ddd.jpg
```

Also another way is to use explode/implode:

```
   <?php
$var1='c:/data/2/some_string/ddd.jpg';
$var2='c:/data/data/2/some_string/ddd.jpg';
$var3='c:/data/some_string/ddd.jpg';



    $data=strrev($var1);
    $test=explode('/',$data);
$newArray=array($test[0],$test[1]);
$newArray=implode('/',$newArray);
$data=strrev($newArray);
    print_r($data);
```

Both ways have the same outcome. You can use whichever you want.

Comment: HI, it is always print  empty string   for example :

$var1 = 'C:\test - GIT\simulation\images\123\image.bmp'

Comment: yes because you are using '\' and not '/'. According to the example the url fields are spited with "/". I have also printed the output of the code so my code is already tested.

Comment: $var1='C:/test - GIT/simulation/images/123/image.bmp'; 
 if you set your url like that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular Expressions.

Try http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html
and https://regex101.com/

If you want to extract only the parent folder from the file you can use this regex pattern:

```
\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*\..*
```

The code should be:

```
$subject='c:/data/2/123132/ddd.jpg';
$pattern='\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*\..*';

$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
if ($success) {
    echo "Match: ".$match[0]."<br />"; 
    echo "Group: ".$match[1]."<br />"; 
}
```